# CircleAvatar not circle

Tags: flutter

I try to make a profile on `UserAccountDrawerHeader()`. I use property `currentAccountPicture:` with `CircleAvatar()` for image user. But the Avatar not circle.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text('Jo'),
                accountEmail: Text('hello@world.com'),
                currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                  child: Text('JA'),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screshoot my app]

what wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your solution

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text('Jo'),
                accountEmail: Text('hello@world.com'),
                currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  maxRadius: 5,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                  child: Text('JA'),
                  
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Problem:

You were using `DrawerHeader` and then placing the `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` as its child which was not taking up enough space.

```dart
DrawerHeader(
              child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text('Jo'),
                accountEmail: Text('hello@world.com'),
                currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  maxRadius: 5,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                  child: Text('JA'),
                  
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
```

Comment: Ahh I see. If I use `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` I don't need a `DrawerHeader`.

Comment: Yes, it will settle itself :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text('Jo'),
                accountEmail: Text('hello@world.com'),
                currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  maxRadius: 5,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                  child: Text('JA'),
                  
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```